# Debug Codeigniter Shoppincart Functions:

Tags: codeigniter

Can I have some help with this, please. This is a Codeigniter script MVC. There is a Controller "Function add to cart" with a Model: "Function get_products" in Models. I cannot see what is wrong here and why the function get_products doesn't execute. Could someone help me please.

This is the Model: get_product which connects to database:

```
function get_product()
{
  $product_id = $this->input->post(‘product_id’);

  $query = $this->db->select(‘product_id, product_name, description, price, photopath’);
  $query = $this->db->from(‘product’);
  $query = $this->db->where(‘product_id’, $product_id); 
  $query = $this->db->get(’‘);
  return $query->result_array();
}
```

This is the Controller called Function add_cart, which add products to the "shopping cart view":

```
public function add_cart()
{

  $thisProduct = $this->Cart_model->add_product();

  if($thisProduct->num_rows() > 0)
  {

  $data = array(‘id’ => $thisProduct[‘product_id’],
               ‘qty’ => 1,
             ‘price’ => $thisProduct[‘price’],
              ‘name’ => $thisProduct[‘product_name’], 
       ‘description’ => $thisProduct[‘description’]
  );

  $this->cart->insert($data);

  }

  $this->load->view(“site_header”);
  $this->load->view(“site_nav”);
  $this->load->view(“shoppingcart”, $data);
  $this->load->view(“site_footer”);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you make many mistakes.
read here: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/128969/